# Intercept load image assets on webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I want to intercept an HTTP request and load the given resource from the web app's assets directory instead. I think loading resources from the assets directory is better than loading resources over the network.

I want to load resource like an image, a font, some HTML, but I am confused. I have accessed files inside the assets directory with the AssetManager. I tried some code and my app crashes.

I am not sure what the issue is. Here is the code I tried:

```
public class WebViewClientImpl extends WebViewClient {

    private Activity activity = null;

    public WebViewClientImpl(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {


        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        activity.startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {

        if(url.startsWith("http://google.com/images/logo.png")){
            return loadFromAssets(url, "images/logo.png", "image/png", "");
        }

        return null;
    }

    private WebResourceResponse loadFromAssets( String url,
        String assetPath, String mimeType, String encoding){

        AssetManager assetManager = this.activity.getAssets();
        InputStream input = null;
        try {
            Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "Loading from assets: " + assetPath);


            input = assetManager.open("/images/logo.png");
            WebResourceResponse response =
                    new WebResourceResponse(mimeType, encoding, input);

            return response;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("WEB-APP", "Error loading " + assetPath + " from assets: " +
                e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```